# yowsup2 no module named _sqlite3

Tags: python, yowsup

I'm having the below error when I try to run the yowsup-cli command to send a message. This is the command I'm running:

```
yowsup-cli demos -c /etc/yowsup-cli.conf -s 'phone number' "text"
```

I'm running it on Linux CentOS 5.11 which comes with python 2.4 preinstalled. I installed python 2.7 which is required for yowsup2 to run but I'm encountering the following error:

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 368, in <module>
    if not parser.process():
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 272, in process
    self.startSendClient()
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 323, in startSendClient
    not self.args["unmoxie"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/demos/sendclient/stack.py", line 20, in __init__
    .pushDefaultLayers(encryptionEnabled)\
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/stacks/yowstack.py", line 51, in pushDefaultLayers
    defaultLayers = YowStackBuilder.getDefaultLayers(axolotl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/stacks/yowstack.py", line 73, in getDefaultLayers
    from yowsup.layers.axolotl import AxolotlSendLayer, AxolotlControlLayer, AxolotlReceivelayer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/layers/axolotl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .layer_send import AxolotlSendLayer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_send.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .layer_base import AxolotlBaseLayer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer_base.py", line 1, in <module>
    from yowsup.layers.axolotl.store.sqlite.liteaxolotlstore import LiteAxolotlStore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/layers/axolotl/store/sqlite/liteaxolotlstore.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .litesenderkeystore import LiteSenderKeyStore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup/layers/axolotl/store/sqlite/litesenderkeystore.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Anyone that had this same error or might help me with it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by copying the module manually to the below path:

```
cp build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_sqlite3.so /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```